# How can I protect "SecretStrings" so that they are not human readable in the compiled EXE file

Tags: c#, security, encryption, compilation, data-protection

When I write code in Visual Studio (C#) then Strings are compiled inside the EXE file.
But if I open the EXE file with a text editor I can find those Strings.

```
    string sMyUser = "admin";
    string sMyPass = "NobodyShouldKnowThis";
    Login(sMyUser, sMyPass);
```

What can I do to protect these strings, so that they are stored in the EXE file in a unreadable format?

If possible I want to leave the strings inside my C# code and not save them in external files.

Comment: [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-6.0) Is better but still wrong.

The right answer is to not store the strings in code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a simple XOR encryption. The program is still readable very well.

```
string sMyUser = XorEncrypt("bgnjm", 3); // "admin";
string sMyPass = XorEncrypt("MlalgzPklvogHmltWkjp", 3); // "NobodyShouldKnowThis";
Login(sMyUser, sMyPass);

private static string XorEncrypt(string text, int key)
{
    string newText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        int charValue = Convert.ToInt32(text[i]); //get the ASCII value of the character
        charValue ^= key; //xor the value
        newText += char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue); //convert back to string
    }
    return newText;
}
```

Here you can encrypt/decrypt your own string:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/raoUBi

Comment: As long as you recognise that this doesn't actually offer any kind of protection, I guess it's OK to just obfuscate the values in the file.

Comment: Using a `StringBuilder` with preallocated `text.Length` would reduce allocations.

Comment: Further this solution fails, if the `charValue` after the xor is out of range for `ConvertFromUtf32`.